# Send Messages to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to build a gift, similar to the [Heartbox](https://en.lovebox.love/) with my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1.

My simpler Version will just be the Raspberry Pi with a screen attached to it anywhere in the world with a wifi-connection. I would like to send something (First text maybe latern an Image) through an app or website and it will be displayed.

Do you maybe have some input for me on how I could tackle this task? Anything helps! And please tell me, if this was the wrong network to ask, I was unsure.

Comment: *If* you can find a similarly broad question on [Raspberry Pi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), it *might* be on-topic over there. It would be better to break the project down into separate parts (e.g. the box, the programming (which itself is likely to need several sub-parts), the battery charging) and tackle them individually, which will lead you to specific questions which can be answered.

Comment: Install Dropbox on the Raspberry Pi and have it continually display an image from your Dropbox called, say, `pi.png` using `feh`. Then wherever you are in the world, save a new image in your Dropbox with that name so the Pi displays the new image.